# Git push doesn't work after adding and committing files

Tags: git

I'm new to Github and Git,  tried to use gitbash on Windows.After adding and committing files ,If I add the git push cmd.. The cli asks for username...  And then a password with no interface to enter password..  What do I do? [image]

Comment: can you share the screens to let people know what is happening.

Comment: If none of the answers work, I've had a similar issue where `unset askpass` has worked

Comment: Just enter your credentials. The password won't be displayed.

Comment: Make sure to type `git config --global credential.helper manager`: wincred is obsolete. And make sure to use the latest Git for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Check the value of `git config credential.helper`: if it is "manager", open the [Windows Credential Manager](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/4026814/windows-accessing-credential-manager) and look if you already have a github.com entry.

If not and if the issue persists, try the same command from a regular CMD (not git bash) and the following simplified PATH:

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set GH=C:\path\to\git
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%
```

(replace "`path\to\git`" with your Git installation folder)

Answer (score 1):

From git bash you should prefer to run the command:

```sh
git config --global credential.helper wincred
```

At that point, running a command like git pull and entering your credentials one time should have it stored for future use. Git has a built-in credentials system that works in different OS environments.

You can get more details on the git website [Git Tools - Credential Storage](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage).

And you should use `git pull` before `git push` if it has been moved to remote server before.

Hope it works!

Comment: I was using windows cmd before now...  So I decided to right click on the folder containing the files I want to push to Github..  Then after the " git push" command..  The prompt to enter username and password, which I did..  After few seconds..  It pushed..  Thanks everyone