# How do I update Git version via Anaconda command prompt?

Tags: git, anaconda

I need to update Git from verson 1.9 to 2.22 and I want to do it via command prompt, I am using Anaconda.

This because I tried to download the exe file from Git website and to run it to update the program but it looks like it does not work.

I tried

```
Git --help
```

and I found out that commands like

```
Git --update
```

does not exist, at least for version 1.9.
I also tried

```
pip install -update Git
```

But it does not work.

Does anybody knows how to do the upgrade?

Comment: I think it's not Git, it's git.

Comment: You cannot install `git` with `pip` — `pip` is a Python package manager, it only installs Python packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED

In the end I solved it by first uninstalling the 1.9 Git version (via Windows uninstall apps tool in OS settings) and **only then** installing the 2.22 via the downoaded exe file from Git website.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the *Windows* exe, it would be easier to download the self-extracting archive [`PortableGit-2.22.0-64-bit.7z.exe`](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.22.0.windows.1/PortableGit-2.22.0-64-bit.7z.exe) and [set your `PATH` accordingly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56286029/6309).

Then the `git.exe` would work.

Answer (score 0):

`conda install -c anaconda git`
I installed the whole package and it worked.